# Parsing Date with Hour 24 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, datetime

I have a CSV file with 8760 hourly data rows and many of them have a time like 24:00. It seems MATLAB doesn't allow the hour number to be 24 (it goes from 0 to 23). I'm not able to figure out a way to parse rows with time 24:00.

MATLAB Example (gives an error):

```
datetime('7/16/02 24:00','InputFormat','MM/dd/yy HH:mm')
```

Same example in R (works fine, i.e., it automatically converts to July 17th, 0:00):

```
as.POSIXct("7/16/02 24:00",format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: Your format is wrong, `MM` is minutes and `mm` is month.

Comment: @Daniel this seems to be *the* answer.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I did not test it, don't have access to Matlab at the moment. Anyone who verified this to work, feel free to write an answer.

Comment: @Daniel: And my matlab is too old and doesn't have `datetime`. But `datevec` is available and seems to parse your solution properly. I guess OP can verify.

Comment: @Daniel, the format for minutes and months in MATLAB are the opposite in R (for whatever reason). http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#inputarg_infmt

Comment: @Bruno, have you checked `help datetime` or `help datestr` in matlab? It would be **very** weird if two functions had different conventions within matlab, see [datestr doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html). Although it would also be a bit of a doosie if there was a typo this big in the reference.

Comment: @Bruno: They are not only opposite to `R`, they are also opposite to `datenum`: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html#inputarg_formatIn The format in your question is correct.

Comment: Guys, I now realize it's kind of a mess of formats. :P I'll post a "solution" to my problem below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, it seems that the formats for minutes and hours are different for different date-related functions in MATLAB. A possible solution is to use `datestr` together with `datetime`.

The same MATLAB example as in the question (it works now):

```
datetime(datestr('7/16/02 24:00','mm/dd/yy HH:MM'),'InputFormat','MM/dd/yy HH:mm')
```

Result:

```
ans = 

   17-Jul-2002 00:00:00
```

The function `datestr` automatically converts the date to July 17th, 0:00 and that is passed to the function `datetime`.

Comment: One of the weirdest matlabisms ever, bordering a bug (and conflicting common sense from multiple aspects). Good job unraveling it. I think you should accept your own answer for transparence.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I agree! haha Thanks to you and others for the inputs and observations! StackOverflow will let me accept my own answer only in 2 days. :P

Comment: Sorry, I had no idea. OK then:)

Comment: That is certainly a weird ass bug. Nice job spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue and I have posted my question yesterday:

> I am using the code below to do parsing for date-time cells in an MS
> Excel sheet with date-time form  of (  01/05/2019 00:00) as in the
> screenshot below.
>
> ```
> clc,clear,close all;
> [num1,data] = xlsread('Book_new.xlsx','sheet1','A1:A30');
> a=datevec(data,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS');
> date=datestr(datenum(a),'dd/mm/yyyy');
> time=datestr(datenum(a),'HH:MM:SS');
> Year=datestr(datenum(a),'yyyy');
> mm=datestr(datenum(a),'mm');
> dd=datestr(datenum(a),'dd');
> yy=datestr(datenum(a),'yyyy');
> [status,message] =xlswrite('motasem.xlsx',str2num(yy),'sheet1','A1:A30');
> [status,message] =xlswrite('motasem.xlsx',str2num(mm),'sheet1','B1:B30');
> [status,message] =xlswrite('motasem.xlsx',str2num(dd),'sheet1','C1:C30');
> [status,message] =xlswrite('motasem.xlsx',string(time),'sheet1','D1:D30');
> ```
>
> When I run the code for example for the 1st 30 readings (half hourly
> readings) it gives me the following error:
>
> ```
> Error using dtstr2dtvecmx
> Failed to convert from text to date number.
> Error in datevec (line 123)
>             y = dtstr2dtvecmx(t,icu_dtformat);
> Error in motasem (line 4)
> a=datevec(data,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS');
> ```
>
> But when I change the range of data to avoid the first reading which
> contains the time 00:00:00 it works and gives the below output : Any
> suggestions, please?

The new code that works is using readtable function as follows:

```
clc,clear,close all;
data = readtable('Book_new.xlsx','Range','A1:A60','ReadVariableNames',false);
A = table2array(data);
yy=datestr(datenum(A),'yyyy');
mm=datestr(datenum(A),'mm');
dd=datestr(datenum(A),'dd');
time=datestr(datenum(A),'HH:MM:SS');
[status,message] =xlswrite('motasem.xlsx',str2num(yy),'sheet1','A1:A30');
[status,message] =xlswrite('motasem.xlsx',str2num(mm),'sheet1','B1:B30');
[status,message] =xlswrite('motasem.xlsx',str2num(dd),'sheet1','C1:C30');
[status,message] =xlswrite('motasem.xlsx',string(time),'sheet1','D1:D30');
```